# Use Teradata python module through Pyspark

Tags: python, pyspark, teradata

I have the following code:

```
# my_code.py

# Imports
import teradata

# Env
CONFIG = config.ini # Teradata ODBC configs

# Thread
def run():
    return teradata.UdaExec(appConfigFile=CONFIG ).connect("${dataSourceName}")
```

*In the previous part, the env variables (ODBCINI, dataSourceName, ...) are correctly set*

When I run it with python (like *python -c "from my_code import run; run()"*), it works.

Now, I want to run **the same code** with pyspark,

I developped the following script:

```
# main.py

# Imports
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession, SparkConf
from my_code import run

# Environment
TERAJDBC_4JAR="/path/to/terajdbc4.jar"
TERAJDBC_CONF="/path/to/terajdbc4.jar"

# Thread
conf = SparkConf("spark.jars", SPARK.)
conf.set("spark.jars", "{},{}".format(TERAJDBC_4JAR, TERAJDBC_CONF))  # set the spark.jars
SPARK = SparkSession.builder \
                .config(conf=conf) \
                .master('yarn') \
                .getOrCreate()
os.environ['HADOOP_HOME'] = SPARK.conf.get("spark.driver.HADOOP_HOME")
os.environ['ARROW_LIBHDFS_DIR'] = SPARK.conf.get("spark.driver.ARROW_LIBHDFS_DIR")
os.environ['CLASSPATH'] = SPARK.conf.get("spark.driver.CLASSPATH")
os.environ['ODBCINI'] = SPARK.conf.get("spark.driver.ODBCINI")
run()
```

to launch **main.py** I used:

```
# Environment
export TERAJDBC_4JAR="/path/to/terajdbc4.jar"
export TERAJDBC_CONF="/path/to/terajdbc4.jar"
export CONFIG_HADOOP_HOME="/path/to/hadoop-client"
export CONFIG_LIBHDFS_DIR="/path/to/libhdfs"
export CLASSPATH="/path/to/classpath"

SPARK_MAJOR_VERSION=2 spark-submit --master yarn \
             --conf "spark.pyspark.python=/path/to/bin/python3" \
             --conf "spark.pyspark.driver.python=/path/to/bin/python3" \
             --conf "spark.driver.ODBCINI=${ODBCINI}" \
             --conf "spark.driver.HADOOP_HOME=${CONFIG_HADOOP_HOME}" \
             --conf "spark.driver.ARROW_LIBHDFS_DIR=${CONFIG_LIBHDFS_DIR}" \
             --conf "spark.driver.CLASSPATH=${CLASSPATH}" \
             --driver-class-path "${TERAJDBC_4JAR},${TERAJDBC_CONF}" \
             --jars "${TERAJDBC_4JAR},${TERAJDBC_CONF}" \
             main.py"
```

This did not works.**The error message is: "teradata.api.DatabaseError: (0, '[I] [. Check that the ODBC driver is installed and the ODBCINI or ODBCINST environment variables are correctly set.')"**

Unfortunatly, ODBCINI is correctly set. How to fix this?

Should i configure the connection with Teradata through ODBC connector in the spark session ? :)

Comment: Is it correctly set? Maybe submit a Python module that displays the values to check. Why include JDBC driver and then submit something using Python/ODBC? If you are going to use Python, maybe `teradatasql` package which does not use ODBC would be a better choice.

Comment: The script works without PySpark, but for test purpose, I need to use this script with pyspark. Unfortunatly, I can't handle this ...

Comment: I think people typically use the JDBC driver to access Teradata from Spark / PySpark.